# Adobe AIR - rtmfp - delay before Neighbor.Connect

Tags: air, rtmfp

When I am testing RTMFP serverless connection, I noticed that there is often a very long delay between the `NetGroup.Connect.Success` and `NetGroup.Neighbor.Connected` events (where I can start an actual P2P communication).

Sometimes it connects immediately and but sometimes it takes several minutes on the same network. I was not able to find any logic in this.

After I have finally received the `Neighbor.Connect`, the posting is quick and stable.

I have tested it on `ADL <-> Android` and `ADL <-> ADL` (Windows 10), but on all browser the rtmfp flash examples behave the same.

So my question is - Is this a common issue and is there a way to minimize this delay in the connection (without any messing with hardware)?

Thanks!